# JSLint and Mocha-Tests

Tags: node.js, jenkins, mocha.js, jslint

I use JSLint and configure a header in each file:

```
/*global Buffer: false, clearInterval: false, clearTimeout: false, console: false, exports: false, global: false, module: false, process: false, querystring: false, require: false, setInterval: false, setTimeout: false, __filename: false, __dirname: false, describe: false, it: false, before: false, after: false */
```

Everything works fine and my jenkins gets happy, but i get a warning for my tests.

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
```

for every expect line

```
 expect(Module).to.be.ok;
```

How can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two options:

```
expect(Module).to.be.ok();
```

or:

```
/*jshint expr: true*/
```

Comment: or change the global jshint config file to ignore this warning

Comment: yep that too. assumed he wanted the in line since he was already doing that.